# Replace string with regex in swift

Tags: regex, swift

I want to replace a portion of a string that matches a regex pattern.

I have the following regex pattern:

```
(.+?)@test\.(.+?)
```

And this is a string replacement pattern:

```
$1@hoge\.$2
```

How can I use them inside Swift code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Swift, you can use [`stringByReplacingMatchesInString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:) for a regex-based replace.

Here is a snippet showing how to use it:

```
let txt = "myname@test.com"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([^@\\s]+)@test\\.(\\w+)", options:nil, error: nil)
let newString = regex!.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(txt, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(txt)), withTemplate: "$1@hoge.$2")
println(newString)
```

**Swift 4.2 update**:

```
let txt = "myname@test.com"
let regex = "([^@\\s]+)@test\\.(\\w+)"
let repl = "$1@hoge.$2"
print( txt.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: repl, options: [.regularExpression]) )
```

Note that I changed the regex to

- `([^@\\s]+)` - matches 1 or more characters other than `@` or whitespace
- `@` - matches `@` literally
- `test\\.(\\w+)` - matches `test.` literally and then 1 or more alphanumeric character (`\w+`).

Note that in the replacement string, you do not need to escape the period.

Comment: I wrote a RegEx replace method that takes a closure: http://eon.codes/blog/2017/08/03/regex-replace-with-closure/

Comment: @GitSync I do not think the current problem needs to be solved with a closure enabled regex. Still, that can be of help to others, sure.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Totally agree that closure is overkill with this problem. But I couldn't find anything on stack or google about replacing with closures so I thought Id mention it.

Comment: @GitSync I think I have seen that somewhere. Maybe something similar. If I find it, I will post a comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My implementation isn't perfect. I think accumulatively appending a string is faster than inPlace substring replace. But I had to move on. I made a note of it in the code for a future improvement opportunity.

Comment: How is it possible to modify those replacement strings "$1", "$2" ? For example "$1".upperCasingFirstLetter() does not work because the compiler sees "$1" instead of the replaced string ?

Comment: @Chris Of course, you cannot perform text manipulations on the replacement pattern, you need to be able to access the match value in order to apply manipulations on it. I have not heard of any way to use an "anonymous function" as a replacement argument to a regex replace methon in Swift yet.