# Can I get all the text between every <p> and </p> in a certain ID

Tags: html, swift, parsing, text, textview

I used the code below but it only gets me the text between one, when it should get me the text between 5 `<p>` and `</p>`

```
>             var myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
            while let idRange = myHTMLString.range(of: "post-51"){
                myHTMLString=myHTMLString.substring(from: idRange.upperBound)
                if let paraRange = myHTMLString.range(of: "<p>"){
                    myHTMLString=myHTMLString.substring(from: paraRange.upperBound)
                    if let paraCloseRange = myHTMLString.range(of: "</p>"){
                        HTMLData = myHTMLString.substring(to: paraCloseRange.lowerBound)
                        textViewer.text = HTMLData
                        myHTMLString = myHTMLString.substring(from: paraCloseRange.upperBound)

                    }else{
                        //Handle paragraph close tag not found
                        print("Handle paragraph close tag not found")
                    }
                }else{
                    //Handle paragraph start tag not found
                    print("Handle paragraph start tag not found")
                }
            }
```

The full HTML string is:`

```
<!-- main content -->
<div id="content" class="main-content-inner col-sm-12 col-md-9">
        <header>
        <h1 class="page-title">Community</h1>
    </header>
<article id="post-51" class="post-51 page type-page status-publish hentry">
    <!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-content">
        <h1>Your Experience, Your Programs</h1>
<p>The Purdue Honors College is dedicated to providing meaningful opportunities to enhance the honors student experience. We are building an interdisciplinary community of scholars by adding value through specialized programming and events that are connected to our pillars. The Honors College strives to create an environment in which every student can feel connected, learn, and grow as they each pursue greatness. To reach your full potential in the Honors College, students should attend at least three honors programs per semester outside of the regular curriculum requirements. We invite you to be a part of one of our many upcoming events as we ignite the imagination of our community and forge the future of our college.</p>
<hr />
<h3>Events Calendar</h3>
<p>The Honors College hosts events to keep students engaged with their peers and the Honors College faculty.</p>
<p><a href="https://honors.purdue.edu/community/calendar/">Click here to learn more about upcoming events in the Honors College.</a></p>
<hr />
<h3>Honors College and Residences</h3>
<p>The new 324,000-square-foot Honors College and Residences is the first of its kind in the state of Indiana. It encourages scholarship and connects students with faculty while being emblematic of the Mission of the Purdue Honors College: from the locally sourced building materials to LEED certification and interactive learning spaces.</p>
<p><a href="https://honors.purdue.edu/community/honors-college-and-residences/">Click here to learn more about the new Honors College and Residences buildings.</a></p>
<hr />
<h3>Honors Network News</h3>
<p><a href="https://honors.purdue.edu/community/honors-network-news/">Click here to view the Honors Network News archive.</a></p>
<hr />
<h3>News</h3>
<p>Stay up to date with news about the Honors College. Learn about the awesome things our students are doing and follow the Honors College on social media.</p>
<p><a href="https://honors.purdue.edu/community/news/">Click here to view more news about the Honors College.</a></p>
<hr />
<h3>Photo Gallery</h3>
<p><a href="https://honors.purdue.edu/community/photo-gallery/">Click here to view photos of Honors College events.</a></p>
<hr />
<h3>Published Works</h3>
<p><a href="https://honors.purdue.edu/community/published-works/">Click here to view the published works of the Honors College.</a></p>
<hr />
<h3>Signature Programs</h3>
<p><a href="https://honors.purdue.edu/community/signature-programs/">Click here to learn more about Signature Programs from the Honors College.</a></p>
<hr />
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article><!-- #post-## -->
`
```

Comment: Yes.You can, try $("#p id ").text() using jquery

Comment: This is on swift. I don't think jquery works with Swift. Am I right?

Comment: Oops,I did'nt notice that.

Comment: You want to parse html page?

Comment: @SergeyDi Im trying to get the text from a webpage that is located under the HTML ID of `post-51`. There are multiple `<p>` and `</p>` and I want to get the text from all of them and print it

Comment: @JunaidJaved post-51 is something like  <div id="post-51"
And you need to get content of all <p> tags inside this div?

Comment: @SergeyDi Yes the id is actually "content" but it is written out as `<div id = "content"` and I want to get the content inside all of the `<p>`tags

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to this to loop though all

after you find the id. Take a look at my comment that it's very import to break the while loop after certain condition is met.

```
 var myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
if let idRange = myHTMLString.range(of: "post-51"){
        myHTMLString=myHTMLString.substring(from: idRange.upperBound)
        while let paraRange = myHTMLString.range(of: "<p>"){
            myHTMLString=myHTMLString.substring(from: paraRange.upperBound)
            if let paraCloseRange = myHTMLString.range(of: "</p>"){
                HTMLData = myHTMLString.substring(to: paraCloseRange.lowerBound)
                textViewer.text = HTMLData
                //AFTER YOU GET THE NEEDED INFORMATION, DO A break HERE to get out of while loop or you will loop through all <p>
                myHTMLString = myHTMLString.substring(from: paraCloseRange.upperBound)

            }else{
                //Handle paragraph close tag not found
                print("Handle paragraph close tag not found")
            }
        }
    }else{
        print("Handle id not found")
    }
```

Comment: It is only going through the while loop once. The errors are not executed either

Comment: Update it is going through the While loop 5 times but the error say that paragraph start tag was not found. Ive looked through the html and its there

Comment: @JunaidJaved Can you post the full html string in your question please?

Comment: I added most of the HTML where the text I want is located. Stack Overflow has a word limit so I can't put all of the HTML code in it. I noticed the ID is content. I have updated the code but still the same thing is occuring

Comment: @JunaidJaved I only see ID post-51 once in your code. I though you told me that there are several id post-51 in the html and you want <p> after each of them? Do you actually mean that you have multiple <p> after the only POST-51?

Comment: Yes sorry if my wording was a bit bad but there is only one post-51 and multiple <p> that have the text that I want

Comment: @JunaidJaved Updated

Comment: It is giving me an error. Are you sure there should be an `if` after the `while` in line 3 of the code

Comment: It works :) but there are still tags in the code `<a> some random website </a>`. Is there a way to get rid of these. Its hyperlinks. Is there a way to take away hyperlinks

Comment: @JunaidJaved That's another topic. Loop at how to use a regex replace here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32607041/5838902

Comment: Will that work if the website in the middle of `<a>` and `</a>` is different every time

Comment: @JunaidJaved Yes. Use keyword <a>.*a> in your replace. You can learn it from google. basically, this means looking for string starts with "<a>", with any characters inside until you find the first "a>". Then you replace it with space

Answer (score 0):

I think that using an **off-screen** web view to temporarily load the HTML and retrieve the contents you're after is not out of the question. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Declared as a property of the class to ensure it is not freed
    // from memory (because we're not adding it to the view hierarchy).
    let webView = UIWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadHTMLString("<html><head></head><body><div id=\"hello\"><p>First</p><p>Second</p><p>Third</p></div></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

        let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('hello').getElementsByTagName('p')).map(function(p) { return p.innerHTML }).join('|')")
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Note that `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` can't handle array responses, so we concatenate the contents of the `p` tags with a pipe `|` character to return it to Swift. You can then split the string on the pipes to get an array back. You can change the delimiter to anything that you're sure will never be present naturally inside the `p` tags.

Also, `Array.prototype.slice.call` is just to convert the `HTMLCollection` that `getElementsByTagName` returns into an array.

Comment: I thought about doing making a webView but the college I'm working with doesn't want it to feel like a web browser. Is there a way I can use the code but not have a webView visible to the user

Comment: It's not visible to the user, look at the code, I'm not adding the web view to the screen, it's just loaded into memory, never displayed.

Comment: That seems to work in a test project I created really quickly. How do I get rid of the "|" that appears after every <p> tag ends

Comment: Do you want all the text joined together? If so, remove the `.join('|')`.

Comment: I got rid of them but it is still showing some text in the console that I don't want. EX: `<a> some link to a website </a>`

Comment: Changing `innerHTML` to `innerText` removes tags from the output.